# Auto-authentication on a dialog produced from an embedded iFrame

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I have embedded an iFrame into my web-page. The iFrame keeps prompting the user to enter their security details via a dialog box which appears on the screen.

I do not have access to the server on which the iFrame is stored, but I do have security details and a username/password that works on this server. I would like to hardcode it so that the dialog box no longer appears - the details are automatically entered via Ruby/JS.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: The authentication dialog which appears: is it an HTTP-Auth window (i.e. a pop-up modal) or is it a standard authentication form for the remote serve (i.e. the request is being redirected to the login page)?

Comment: @pjmorse It is a pop-up modal dialog box - a new, separate window. It reads "A username and password are being requested by http://website.com. The site says: "Login" and has two fields; one for username, the other for password. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, that sounds like the HTTP-Auth window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct in assuming this is an HTTP-Auth window (that is, the remote HTTPD itself - Apache or Nginx or IIS or whatever - is requesting authentication, not the site software) you can provide a login and password as part of the iframe `src` URL, e.g.

```
 <iframe src="http://login@password:website.com"></iframe>
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach if the login and password are sensitive, but your choices are really either putting the login and password in a place where the end user can find them, like this, or making another arrangement with the owners of `website.com` to auto-authorize users of your site.